# Category Manager: How to show a list of a category AND ONLY its subcategory?

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, category, subcategories

I have hundreds of categories on one Joomla site.

Using the Joomla administrator category manager, I'd like to find a way to list a category AND ONLY its children subcategories.

To be clear, I'd like a category AND its subcategories (*but only that category and its subcatagories*) to be listed when I use the search filters.

Here is an example:

Under the category Asia, I have 22 subcategories (i.e. countries such as Bali, Bhutan, Borneo, etc.)

I can use the Category Manager to search for Asia, but then it only shows Asia and not it's subcategories.

[image]

I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious (an easy way to do this exists, and I just haven't figured it out yet), or if this is more of a 'wish list' item for the Joomla CMS Project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried and couldn't find a way to do what you're wanting either (Joomla 3.8.2).

Comment: Thanks Drew! I was trying to avoid 'endless scrolling,' and missing the category (many categories have the same names (my eyes go blurry after staring at screens all day). I'm just setting the search filter to 'All' and using ctrl-f in my browser - this speeds things up immensely.